# How to import Python modules to my node?

Tags: python, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS Kinetic with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I am trying to connect two ROS nodes (publisher/subscriber, both of them). In one Python node, I am trying to use some modules I had already programmed, which are embedded in **pyib2c** module.

```
import pyib2c
```

This module also imports some Python modules. When I try to run my node, I receive the following error:

*ImportError: cannot import name XXXXX* , where XXXXX are the modules imported by my pyib2c module.

I have already uncommented the  * catkin_python_setup() * in the CMakeList of my package. The setup.py is:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

# fetch values from package.xml
setup_args = generate_distutils_setup(
    packages=['pyib2c'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'})

setup(**setup_args)
```

I have also created a **init.py** file which is:

```
 from . import tabulate
 from . import pyib2c
```

My Python node, the module  *pyib2c*, the **init.py** and the setup.py are them all at the same level in my_package/src. However, it turns out to display the same mistake if I keep the pyib2c in a src folder.

How  can I make my node import the modules I need?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283140/how-to-import-python-modules-to-my-node?/) by [FerCipri](https://answers.ros.org/users/33765/fercipri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-02-19

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-21**:
Have you compiled your package? In order for you to use the module in your package `catkin` needs to run your `setup.py`.

**Comment by [FerCipri](https://answers.ros.org/users/33765/fercipri/) on 2018-02-21**:
Yes, I have run catkin_make at my catkin_ws and it works perfectly. The trouble comes at the point of rosrun my node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The module (i.e. the source files) as well as the `__init__.py`needs to be placed in `<path_to_your_package>/src/<your_package>` (at least by convention and as explained [in the documentation](http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/installing_python.html#modules), it might work another way).

The `setup.py` needs to be in `<path_to_your_package>`.

Then `catkin_python_setup` should be able to find everything correctly and, hopefully, you should be able to import everything properly.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FerCipri](https://answers.ros.org/users/33765/fercipri/) on 2018-02-21**:
I have tried as you said and didn't work. In fact, it stopped recognising my **pyib2c** python module =S

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-02-22**:
Did you run catkin_make once more after reorganizing?
You can check if it has been installed properly if the module can be found below `devel/lib/python2.7/<yourpackage>`, if i am correct.